Do large integers increase the expressiveness of $\mathsf{SUBSET-SUM}$?
We can consider any set $A$ of integers as a nondeterministic "subset-sum circuit" for strings represented as numbers in some range $[-2^N, 2^N]$, accepting an integer $n$ within this range if and only if some subset of $A$ sums to $n$. For any such subset-sum circuit, we say that its size is the cardinality of the circuit, plus the largest binary length of any of its elements.
Defining $\mathsf{SS}$ as the set of decision problems decidable by subset-sum circuits of polynomial size, we see that $\mathsf{SS} = \mathsf{NP/poly}$. Clearly $\mathsf{SS} \subseteq \mathsf{NP/poly}$ because subset-sum is expressible by a vanilla nondeterminsitic circuit. Conversely, $\mathsf{NP/poly} \subseteq \mathsf{SS}$ is obtained by a slight modification of the proof that $\mathsf{SAT}$ reduces to $\mathsf{SUBSET-SUM}$.
Now define $\mathsf{LSS}$ as the set of decisions problems computed by large subset-sum circuits, where only the cardinality of the subset-sum circuit is required to be polynomial, but the elements of the circuit can be unboundedly positive or negative.
Note that we can computably find a minimum cardinality subset-sum circuit computing a given finite set of integers, even though this prima facie quantifies over an infinite number of $\mathsf{SS}$ circuits. This is because the statement "$A$ is decided by a subset-sum circuit of cardinality $k$" is expressible in Presburger arithmetic, which is known to be decidable, and we can search for the minimum $k$, and then search for a circuit of size $k$.
Question: How big is the complexity class $\mathsf{LSS}$?
It seems plausible that $\mathsf{LSS} = \mathsf{NP/poly}$, because standard proofs of $\mathsf{SAT} \leq \mathsf{SUBSET-SUM}$ require $\Omega(1)$ subset-sum elements per clause and literal, but I have not been able to rule out even that $\mathsf{LSS} = \mathsf{ALL}$.
